# Kubutnu fix mouse pointer after installing new kernel

Tags: kernel, kubuntu, mouse, kde, desktop-environments

After compiling `rt` kernel on ubuntu which i have `kde-plasma` my mouse cursor pointer appear something like below screen shot:

[image]

when i take a screen shot with `spectacle` mouse pointer is fine

how can i resolve this problem and changing/rebooting doesn't fix